# Simple proof of $\phi \rightarrow \neg \neg \phi$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, first-order-logic

I have constructed a very simple axiomatic proof of $\phi \rightarrow \neg \neg \phi$, but it's so simple I doubt it. Here it is:

1. $\phi$ Assumption
2. $\neg \phi$ Assumption
3. $\neg \neg \phi$ ($\neg$I)
4. $\phi \rightarrow \neg \neg \phi$ ($\rightarrow$I) $\square$

I have derived $\neg$I independently, and $\rightarrow$I is just the deduction theorem, which I've derived also. Can anyone spot an error?

Comment: What is the $\neg I$ rule you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valid (and well-known) argument, assuming that the $\neg I$ rule you proved is the following or similar:

> From $\Gamma, A \vdash B$ and $\Gamma,A \vdash \neg B$ infer $\Gamma \vdash \neg A$.

You're just instantiating it with $\Gamma$ set to $\{ \varphi \}$, $A$ to $\neg \varphi$, and $B$ to $\varphi$. Of course, if you were to go through the proofs of the deduction theorem and the $\neg I$ rule and wrote down the actual Hilbert proof starting from the three axioms, it wouldn't look that simple anymore.